# Alfresco 3.3. community won't start again

Tags: java, alfresco, ubuntu-server

Ubuntu-server Alfresco was working fine before, but now I get some errors. I'm doing nothing except changing the Admin password via Web-interface and cleaning of old log files.

Now I get 404 error. The log is provided below:

```
11:40:10,390 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.alfresco.service.cmr.rendition.RenditionServiceException: 09250000 Unable to find rendering action root node.
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.checkRenderingActionRootNodeExists(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:199)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.findActionNode(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:154)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.findOrCreateActionNode(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:177)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.saveRenditionDefinition(RenditionDefinitionPersisterImpl.java:143)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionServiceImpl.saveRenditionDefinition(RenditionServiceImpl.java:233)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$1.doWork(ThumbnailRegistry.java:160)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$1.doWork(ThumbnailRegistry.java:149)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:508)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.initThumbnailDefinitions(ThumbnailRegistry.java:148)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.access$400(ThumbnailRegistry.java:49)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry$RegistryLifecycle.onBootstrap(ThumbnailRegistry.java:271)
        at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.onApplicationEvent(ThumbnailRegistry.java:255)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailRegistry.onApplicationEvent(ThumbnailRegistry.java:49)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:294)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:419)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?  I can provide additional information if you ask; just tell me what you want to see.

So, I've done all what Gagravarr said, thanks for Him. Error "root node" has disappeared.
I got some new errors but all been fixed, except one:
Will try to resolve it myself. If not I will ask here again. Thanks!

Comment: Alfresco 3.3 is very odd, a huge a number of bugs have been fixed since it came out. Is there a reason why you're on that version?

Comment: This version was installed by previous administrator. Now I should transfer all data to the new server with 4.2, but I can't do it because Alfresco does not start.

I also have the ACP file, but this bigger 4Gb, and  how I know, Alfresco do not support import ZIP or APC files more of 4Gb. It is possible to split this file? If it possible then I can ignore problem with old version of Alfresco.

Comment: Just drop the new wars in, Alfresco will auto-upgrade for you on startup. (Take a backup in case though!)

Comment: "Just drop the new wars in" sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Replace your 3.3 wars with the 4.2 ones, update the config, take a backup, and start tomcat. Alfresco will upgrade the repo for you

Comment: Thanks you, Sir. Will try it right now.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, yesterday alfresco community was working fine. Now I start the alfresco again and its giving this error out of sudden. I had only added tenants. Also I replaced the war files but still its giving this error. Any idea ? thanks